# How do I emit code and inject it into a loaded assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I've built some Types dynamically using System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit, want to compile those into IL code in memory, and inject that IL code into an assembly loaded in memory - there is no need to save any of this to disk. Maybe my stated plan is wrong. Open to other suggestions about how to get that CodeCompileUnit instance to the said destination.

Comment: Why do you need to inject the types into an already-loaded assembly? Why can you not inject them into an assembly that you are currently building?

Comment: @Justice: That's a good point - it's a curiosity more than anything. I suppose if I had to contrive scenarios possible ones are: to sidestep filesystem permissions about building assemblies by just working in memory; or maybe to inject code into an assembly and dynamically invoke it to inspect things without the need to recompile the app.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do this.  If there is, I'd like to know as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inject code into an existing (already loaded) assembly using `ICorDebug` interfaces.  Edit and Continue does it.

Compute your delta bytes and call `ICorDebugModule2::ApplyChanges`.  See the [MDbg sample code](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2004/09/30/236281.aspx) for more details.

Once upon a time we used `ICorDebugModule::GetEditAndContinueSnapshot` and kin, but these are now deprecated.

**Update** If you don't care about injecting code into an already-loaded assembly, just using `Reflection.Emit` to create a new assembly is more efficient and a lot easier.

Comment: This solution directly answers the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use System.Reflection.Emit namespace and create a dynamic, in-memory assembly.

Alternative is to use CodeDom to generate & compile code, then call into it.

XMLSerialization() does the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to manipulate IL. It's a powerfull tool, though it somehow lacks documentation.